# Validation plugin in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jQuery validation plugin in my project. But I am getting an error:

> TypeError: jQuery("#formID").validationEngine is not a function

My calling function:

```
jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
```

I am including all these scripts:

```
<script src="js/validation/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/validation/jquery_validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/validation/validation_id.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/validation/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/validation/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: And where is your own script with the calling function? Is it in file `validation_id.js`?

Comment: I just write calling function in script. no other script. and no it my own file form.php

Comment: And is this calling function placed after the call to the libraries?

Comment: Samuel Caillerie: yes i call it after all javascripts which i mention above

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call it this way

```
$(function(){
   $("#formID").validationEngine('attach');
});
```

to run it properly.

Comment: can u check in developer bar if all js are loading properly.

Comment: Yes i check it. All js loading properly.